# Can servlet attribute names contain a hyphen -?

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

Can servlet attribute names contain a hyphen `-`?

Because, I tried to retrieve the attributes from the request set in the `doPost` in my servlet, but the result is not what I'm looking for.

In my servlet I have this :

```
String X_USER = request.getParameter("X-User");
request.setAttribute("X-User", X_USER);

String YYYY_YYYY = request.getParameter("Y_CODE");
request.setAttribute("Y-Code", YYYY_YYYY);
```

In my JSP where I want to show these attributes I do this:

```
<li>${X-User}</li>
<li>${Y-Code}</li>
```

The problem is that I'm getting 0 instead of the parameter value.

Comment: First question : did you try without the "-"?

Comment: Why do you get the session then don't use it?

Comment: Are you trying to store the parameters in the `session` because currently you are storing them as attributes of the request object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concrete problem is not the HTTP request parameter, but the EL variable name. All Java keywords and identifiers are illegal in EL variable names.

The `-` is a subtraction operator in Java (and also in EL). How should the EL processor know if you meant to use an attribute with the literal name `X-User` or the result of an integer subtraction of `${User}` from `${X}`? It's by specification interpreted as latter which also explains the numeric result of `0`.

Just use underscore or camelcase instead, like as in normal Java.

```
request.setAttribute("Y_User", X_USER);
request.setAttribute("Y_Code", Y_CODE);
```

```
${X_User}
${Y_Code}
```

If you absolutely need to access a request attribute containing a hyphen in EL, then use the brace notationon the request scope map:

```
${requestScope['X-User']}
${requestScope['Y-User']}
```

The same applies to request parameters, by the way, which you don't necessarily need to copy over into the request scope in the servlet:

```
${param['X-User']}
${param['Y-Code']}
```

#### See also:

- [EL 3.0 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr341/index.html)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Answer (score 0):

You can use implicit object of jsp as

```
response.getAttribute("X-User");
response.getAttribute("Y-Code");
```

As you're setting attribute from servlet there is no need to get it via jstl.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) that solved my problem :)   
Bthe way : "Are you trying to store the parameters in the session because currently you are storing them as attributes of the request object... "  ?  Can you please give the right wya to store them in the sesssion ?